Why I can't call class extension function inside corresponding scope?
I have some class with extension function, for example:
class SampleClass {

    fun NavGraphBuilder.navGraph() { }
}

When I try to call this function inside NavGrapghBuilder scope it doesn't work
 val sampleClass = SampleClass()
 NavHost(navController = rememberNavController(), startDestination = Player) {
    sampleClass.navGraph() // Unresolved reference: navGraph
 }

NavHost is function that has trailing lambda with reciever:
@Composable
public fun NavHost(
    // ... 
    builder: NavGraphBuilder.() -> Unit
): Unit


navGraph is an extension of NavGraphBuilder so you cannot call it on a SampleClass object. But you do need a SampleClass object as an additional receiver, so you need to provide that somehow, for example like this:
NavHost(navController = rememberNavController(), startDestination = Player) {
    with(sampleClass) { navGraph() }
}

